# How to make ModelForm for User Model validate empty input fields in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

So i have a `ModelForm` created for `User` model in `Django`. I have a registration view where this form is being used. However, when I submit the form with some empty fields, the submission works totally fine. I want the form to not submit when any fields are empty.

I realise that in a custom Model, we can assign the property to fields - `blank = False , null = False` and when we create the `ModelForm` on it, the form submission will handle empty input validation for us. However, for the User Model class which is in-built, I cannot add the above mentioned properties to the fields.

I do not want to handle the validation on frontend using JavaScript/JQuery

ModelForm -

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserForm(ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=PasswordInput())
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields =  ('username','first_name','last_name','email','password')
```

In the above form, if the `first_name` field is left empty before submission, it will not throw any error.

For example, I have a custom class which has fields for ex -

```
class Owner(BaseModel):
    # ID
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=10, null= False, blank= False)
```

So, If I have a `ModelForm` made out of `Owner` Model, and I try to submit the form without the `contact` field, I will not be able to do it.

How to implement the same behavior for in-built `User` Model class.

Comment: You should look into using Custom-User rather than User, it is very limiting. https://wsvincent.com/django-custom-user-model-tutorial/

Comment: I have 2 types of users (models) , Owner and Customer. Both have OntoOne relationship with User Model. In that case, how will I have 2 AUTH_USER_MODEL in my project ?